# Why can't we allow one user one i.p?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-accounts

Consider the following scenario:

Imagine that there were two people let us consider them as A and B. User A works at night  and used to use superuser at night. User B works at day and used to use superuser at day

Now as per the community rules if user A gets blocked with his account then obviously user B can't access his/her superuser account due to their IP

And the users A and B may like to cheat superuser by voting each others. So why can't we allow only one user per i.p?

Comment: It sounds like user A has ruined it for user B by breaking the rules. user B should talk to user A, and user B should email the team.

Comment: IP bans are insanely rare, user A doing stuff is never going to get an IP banned (it'd have to be tons of "users" from an IP or something similar). If A and B are voting for each other there's automatic detection that will tell the mods. The developers are smart people, they have already though of all this.

Comment: If I were user B I would've banned user A a long time ago.

Comment: Only one user per IP? I access SuperUser from behind a network that is shared with 3000 more people. All 3000 people share the same external IP. So, by your opinion, only one of us should be allowed to access SuperUser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "can't alow one user one IP".

If you're advocating that a user must be allowed to interact on a site from only **one** allowed IP, then that's a stupid suggestion. With DHCP IP addresses are recycled across many users and by such a method we're talking about blocking a *lot* of legitimate users out there.

Account suspensions are not applied at IP level, neither are account blocks. IP bans are there but **only** when there's a considerate amount of spam being generated from the originating IP

Comment: I believe this is the automated network-level IP ban for low quality, but it's really hard to tell.

Comment: @Josh true; automated low quality bans are really exceptional for [su]; and IP level low quality filters even more so.